# Visual Studio 2015 and IISExpress bindings - Administrator access required to launch IISExpress

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I added an additional binding to my `~/.vs/config/applicationhost.config` to point to my internal IP, so I could test a site from another device on my local network.

i.e.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3510:192.168.178.33" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:3510:localhost" />
```

I have since removed the first line above, but now I can't run IISExpress without administrator privileges because it won't bind to `localhost:3510` without admin access. It won't remember the binding for the next time I launch (not in admin mode).

I want to revert to the original binding - so `localhost:3510` works without running VS in admin mode. Any ideas please?

Comment: You need to learn netsh and then configure the reserved URLs.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi.I ended up changing the port in the project settings and upon launch IIS express was able to use the new port. That's a workaround I can live with.